# Why is moving/copying files to USB 3 so slow?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd

If I try to move a large amount of data, say 100GB, from my internal laptop SSD drive to my USB 3 SSD Seagate backup drive, the data rate runs very low (about 50KB/s) and it's calculated to take days. Is this because there are many files and moving a large file would be faster?

So I'm trying now to compress and move a zip file since it seems that moving large files is much faster that moving the same data size but with many small files. Can anyone tell me how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sounds like a cliche your speed is determined by the slowest link in the chain.

Transfer rates between drives can vary depending on their read/write speed. So you could find you have a USB 3 and a really fast external SSD, but a damaged USB port, slow cable or slow internal drive.

A good start would be to transfer a smaller file and see what result you get. If it runs the same then you need to have a look at your hardware setup. Try using a different USB cable and port is a good start.

See how that works out for you.

Comment: More info: Most laptops that support USB 3 have some USB ports that support USB 3 and more USB ports that don't. Use the blue port, or if you don't have a blue port use one with special markings. Also, USB 2 cables and USB 3 cables are different, USB 3 cables have extra pins and wires.

Answer (score 1):

You might check if you disabled the on-access scanning of the virusscanner. Otherwise it checks all the files you copy, and that slows down the process.